# How to apply predefined colors to a tree diagram in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel and I've this table

product class         perc

PROD-A  II Class       1%

PROD-B  I Class       10%

PROD-C  V Class       59%

PROD-D  III Class     20%

PROD-E  V Class       10%

Using a tree diagram I can obtain this

[image]

I'd like to apply a style using this colors

[image]

and so obtain this tree diagram

[image]

That now I've built by hand.

Is it possible and, if yes, how?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: You will have to use VBA to "automatically" apply the custom chart colors to the series data, if you don't with to apply the colors by hand.